# How to use caret functions to achieve the same results as this for loop? Classification Random Forest caret

Tags: r, classification, random-forest, cross-validation, r-caret

I want to run monte carlo cv 100 times on my data, my data is 2 class classification
I want to use the caret package to achieve the same thing, mainly I'm confused about how to average the results of accuracy for example using caret?

```
# Initialize data for Binary classification
dataset$ID <- factor(dataset$ID)

# Initialize number of iterations
num_iter=100 

# Vectors to store results
acc_vec<-c()

# Function with for loop

    rf <- function(dataset)
    {
      for (i in 1:num_iter)
      {
        trainIndex <-createDataPartition(dataset$ID, p=0.8,list=FALSE)
        dataset_train <-dataset[trainIndex, ]
        dataset_test <-dataset[-trainIndex, ]
        rf <- randomForest(ID~., data=dataset_train, importance=TRUE) 
        x_test <- dataset_test[, -1]
        y_test <- dataset_test$ID

        predictions <- predict(rf, x_test)

        acc_vec <- append(acc_vec, accuracy(actual= y_test, predicted= predictions))

      }

      print(mean(acc_vec))
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the same author of `caret`, there is the brand new environment for modelling called [`tidymodels`](https://www.tidymodels.org/), that it could be helpful to make easy modelling.

Here a canonical example, with a Monte Carlo CV.

```
library(tidymodels)

 # load some fake data and create train and test
data(cells)
set.seed(123)
cell_split <- initial_split(cells %>% select(-case),  strata = class)

train <- training(cell_split)
test  <- testing(cell_split)
```

Now you've to set up the workflow, adding the cross validation (probably you have to install the `ranger` - in this case- package):

```
# first setup your model
rf_spec <- 
  rand_forest(trees = 100) %>% 
  set_engine("ranger") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")
```

Remember you can also create grids of hyperparameters for tuning.

Now you create your validation strategy:

```
set.seed(123)
# I've put 10, you can change parameters
cross_val_mc <- mc_cv(train, prop = .5, times = 10)
```

Now you define your workflow:

```
set.seed(123)
rf_wf <- 
  workflow() %>%
  add_model(rf_spec) %>%
  add_formula(class ~ .)
```

And fit your resample:

```
set.seed(123)
rf_fit_rs <- 
  rf_wf %>% 
  fit_resamples(cross_val_mc)

collect_metrics(rf_fit_rs)

# A tibble: 2 x 6
  .metric  .estimator  mean     n std_err .config             
  <chr>    <chr>      <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <chr>               
1 accuracy binary     0.824    10 0.00308 Preprocessor1_Model1
2 roc_auc  binary     0.896    10 0.00352 Preprocessor1_Model1
```

Comment: @LUCA does it somewhat help?